# Javascript: loop through all records within an object with an irregular key

Tags: javascript, arrays

UPDATED

I've got an object `var myObject = {};`

I build it using a key like so:

```
myObject[key] = {
   name: ...
};
```

So imagine I have created three records:

```
myObject[13] = {...};
myObject[281] = {...};
myObject[76] = {...};
```

I now want to loop through the object as if it were an array.

```
var i,
    length = myObject.length;     // ?? Problem here 'cos it ain't an array

for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    ????
};
```

How can I refer to the three elements at `????`? I don't know the numbers 13, 281 & 76, and `myObject[0]` is not going to find the first record.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't be using an array if your keys aren't consecutive. Use an object instead:

```
var myObject = {};
```

To loop over an object's keys, you use the `for..in` syntax:

```
for (var key in myObject) {
    var value = myObject[key];
}
```

To make your current code work, you'd have to loop over *all* of the keys and check to see if they have values:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var value = myArray[i];

    if (typeof value === 'undefined') continue;

    console.log(key, ' -> ', value)
}
```

Comment: @Derek: Well, an array is an object, but an object isn't an array.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, fellas. I actually am using an object. I declare `var myArray = {};`  I'll fix the question. Sorry!

Comment: BTW - why does Crockford say `for ... in...` is evil?

Comment: I think it's because you loop over the objects prototype and its methods, right?

Comment: @Nick: It's not evil. It's just not meant to be used for arrays. `for...in` iterates over the properties of an object. You're not interested in those when working with an array. Also, there's no guarantee that the array values will be returned in the proper order, as objects don't have any order to them.

Comment: Crockford does say that `for...in` needs to be filtered using the `loopedObject.hasOwnProperty(key)` method/check. (most of the time it doesn't really make a difference, but some libs do mess with prototypes). And yes, `for...in` is for objects that don't have a length property

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen. Happy New Year to you all.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a modern JavaScript engine:

```
myArray.forEach(function(val, key) {
    // val = the value
    // key = the index
});
```

And that's it. To get its size (3, in this case)...

```
var size = myArray.reduce(function(prev) {
    return ++prev;
}, 0);
```

---

If you want this to work in older browsers, you'll need to do something else. The easiest solution would probably be to implement something like this yourself:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i ++) {
    var val = myArray[i];
    if (typeof val !== "undefined") {
        console.log(val);
    }
}
```

To get its size, it's a similar endeavor (that you could combine with the above method if you're doing both):

```
var size = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i ++) {
    if (typeof myArray[i] !== "undefined")
        size ++;
}
```

If you want to use `forEach` and `reduce` like the above, you'll need to find a shim (basically, you'll need to implement those functions yourself). I'd recommend the [larger of the two `forEach` shims on this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [the `reduce` shim on this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), or use [a library that shims them all](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim).